# What is the VB's "AndAlso" equivalent in PHP?

Tags: php, vb.net, operators, logical-operators, and-operator

*Also, does the `And` operator already acts like an `AndAlso`, or both exists in a different way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`&&` is the short-circuiting logical "And" operator, so it is equivalent of `AndAlso` in VB.
`&` is bitwise "And" and does not short-circuit, so it is equivalent to `And` in VB.

Comment: Ok, so `and` stays `and`?

Comment: PHP `&&` == VB `AndAlso`

Comment: Note that PHP `&&` and PHP `and` are doing the same (but with different precedence, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Comment: @Sven Good point.  I always use `&&` simply because it's familiar C-syntax.

Comment: Ok, so there is no real `And` in PHP where it evaluates what is on both sides (that is not an VB's `AndAlso`)? If there's no such `And`, it means that if the thing before the `And` is false, the second things after will never be evaluated? So the only thing that differentiate the `And` and the `&&` is their precedence. Am I right all the way?

Comment: No.  `&` in PHP is equivalent to `And` in VB.